# how to use group by with min() function

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a query that give me the minimum order date and group by total paid, payment method, name, and phone number
all from the same table except the customer name from a different table.

The problem I'm facing is since I'm using min(date) I should use group by, and that will make no since, because every order has a different id so it will give me the same order since there is no minimum date for every order! still I will have a duplicated records.

my query is something like this:

```
SELECT order_id, total_paid, payment_method, c.name, phone, min(date) FROM orders
LEFT JOIN customers c 
GROUP BY total_paid, payment_method, c.name, phone, order_id
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or Snowflake?

Comment: Question does not translate well please clarify by addin sample data and expected output as text

Comment: @GokhanAtil snowflake

Comment: Thanks, I updated the tags of your post. Have you checked the response of Koushik? You need to use subquery but I think you need to reconsider your grouping columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but need to do one more steps.
Using a subquery you can calculate minimum order date and group by total paid, payment method, name, and phone number and the join back to main table to get expected data.

```
SELECT order_id, total_paid, payment_method, c.name, phone, min(date) FROM orders
LEFT JOIN customers c on c.id = customer_id --I assumed.
JOIN 
(SELECT total_paid tpaid, payment_method pmethod, c.name name, phone ph, min(date) mindate FROM orders
LEFT JOIN customers c  on c.id = customer_id --I assumed.
GROUP BY total_paid, payment_method, c.name, phone ) subq  -- this is calculating data for min date. 
ON subq.tpaid=total_paid  and subq.pmethod=payment_method  and subq.name=c.name and subq.ph=phone and subq.mindate =date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to get the ROW with the lowest date (for customer_id), then [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) and [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) are here to help:

```
SELECT 
   o.order_id, 
   o.total_paid, 
   o.payment_method, 
   c.name, 
   o.phone,
   o.date
FROM orders AS o
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON o.customer_id = c.id  
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id ORDER BY O.date) == 1
```

But that doesn't seem like what you have asked.

I am deeply failed to internally find the question you are trying to answer from `ordrers` and `customers` that is grouped by total paid. Where-as summing total paid  per customer makes sense, but then you have no problem using `min(date)`. Which is why I went with the QUALIFY as it doesn't seem like you want to group by from an aggregation perspective, but you want to restrict, thus the ROW_NUMBER to order/rank the results, and the QUALIY to avoid needing to do a sub-select filter, which would look like:

```
SELECT 
   order_id, 
   total_paid, 
   payment_method, 
   name, 
   phone,
   date
FROM (
    SELECT 
       o.order_id, 
       o.total_paid, 
       o.payment_method, 
       c.name, 
       o.phone,
       o.date
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id ORDER BY O.date) AS rn
    FROM orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN customers c
        ON o.customer_id = c.id  
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

but this also brings to light that if you orders/customers are join like guessed, you don't need to do the join inside subselect, which is an important thing to do as late as possible, when working on really large datasets. Thus that should really be written:

```
SELECT 
   o.order_id, 
   o.total_paid, 
   o.payment_method, 
   c.name, 
   o.phone,
   o.date
FROM (
    SELECT 
       order_id, 
       total_paid, 
       payment_method, 
       phone,
       date
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY date) AS rn
    FROM orders
) AS o
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON o.customer_id = c.id  
WHERE rn = 1
```